# I cant get an argument in def to define colour it comes out as black only

Tags: python, colors, arguments, turtle-graphics

Please see my code below.

When it runs all the flowers turnout black.

The flowers are created by calling a function flower and passing several arguments in inclusive of 3 colour names.

There must be something i am over looking but i can figure it out, all the flower colours turn out black.

Would really appreciate some

```
import turtle
import random

fred=turtle.Turtle()
fred.speed(100)

def flower(x,y,petal_num,petal_col,center_col,square_col):
    fred.penup()
    fred.goto(x,y)
    fred.pendown()

    fred.begin_fill()
    fred.color = str(petal_col)

    for petal in range (petal_num):
        for arc in range(2):
            fred.circle(80,100)
            fred.left(80)
        fred.left(360/petal_num)

    fred.end_fill()

    fred.begin_fill()
    fred.color = str(center_col)
    fred.penup()
    fred.goto(x,y-40)
    fred.pendown()
    fred.circle(40)
    fred.end_fill()

    fred.hideturtle()

    fred.penup()
    fred.goto(x,y)
    fred.pendown()

    fred.color = str(square_col)
    def square():
        for i in range (4):
            fred.forward(35)
            fred.right(90)

    for pattern in range(36):
        square()
        fred.right(10)

flower(-200,-200,5,"honeydew","c","lavenderblush")
flower(200,200,7,"skyblue","yellow","cyan")
flower(-200,200,6,"salmon","deepskyblue","lightpink")
flower(200,-200,8,"skyblue","yellow","cyan")
flower(0,0,4,"skyblue","yellow","cyan")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, rewrite these user property settings:

```
fred.color = str(petal_col)
fred.color = str(center_col)
fred.color = str(square_col)
```

into turtle method invocations:

```
fred.color(petal_col)
fred.color(center_col)
fred.color(square_col)
```

Second, change the `"c"` argument below:

```
flower(-200,-200,5,"honeydew","c","lavenderblush")
```

to an actual color:

```
flower(-200, -200, 5, "honeydew", "cyan", "lavenderblush")
```

and your program should bloom.